# How can I use a single array to fill 3 arguments of a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sure the answer is somewhere online, but I'm wording it wrong and nothing comes up.

Anyone know how I could take a function like: `book.set_colour_RGB(0x21, 251, 228, 228)`
which requires 3 arguments for R,G and B, and instead use an array `RGB=[251,228,228]`, so that the function would become:

`book.set_colour_RGB(0x21, x(RGB))` where x is a mystery function I'm looking for that knows to use 3 arguments because the length of RGB is 3.

I get in this case I could use `book.set_colour_RGB(0x21, RGB[0],RGB[1],RGB[2])` and it really wouldn't be that difficult. But I was just curious if there was a way to make it tidier and easier to use, particularly for functions with many more arguments.

Thanks peeps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the "unpacking operator":

```
rgb = [251, 228, 228]
book.set_colour_RGB(0x21, *rgb)
```

A similar operator `**` exists that works with `dict`s and produces keyword arguments, instead of how `*` works with `list`s/`tuple`s and produces positional arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. And it's super simple. Isn't python great?; I learned about the exec() function yesterday; now this. What a great week this is. 